# Ruby on rails File Upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Today i have a little problem containing a File Upload.

First some Infos:

Rubyversion: 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
Railsversion: Rails 3.1.1

Needed Code:
My Form

```
        <%= form_for @label, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
            <% if @label.errors.any? %>
                    <div id="error_explanation">
                            <h2><%= pluralize(@label.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this label from being saved:</h2>

                            <ul>
                            <% @label.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                                    <li><%= msg %></li>
                            <% end %>
                            </ul>
                    </div>
            <% end %>
            <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :file %><br />
                    <%= f.file_field :file %>
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
                    <%= f.submit %>
            </div>
    <% end %>
```

My Model:

```
class Label < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :file
    attr_reader :file

    def file=(file)
            log = Logger.new(Rails.root.join("log/label.log").to_s)
            log.info "file-Action called"
            path=file.tempfile.to_path.to_s
            filename="labellist.csv"
            dest=Rails.root.join("app/assets/csv/").join(filename).to_s
            FileUtils.cp(path, dest)
            csv=CsvLabelParser.new
            log.info "New Parser initialized!"
            csv.parse_csv(dest)
            log.info "Variables: path: #{path.inspect} <-----> dest: #{dest.inspect}"
    end
end
```

My Parser

```
class CsvLabelParser
    require 'csv'

    def initialize
            @logger=Logger.new(Rails.root.join("log/parser.log").to_s)
    end

    def logger
            @logger
    end

    def parse_csv(path)
            counter = 0
            read_handle = File.open(path, "rb")
            content = read_handle.read
            self.logger.info "CONTENT: #{content.inspect}"
            read_handle.close

            content.each_line do |line|
                    if counter != 0
                            csv_array=line.split(";")
                            self.logger.info "CSV-Array No. #{counter}: #{csv_array.inspect}"
                            label=Label.new

                            label.labnr=csv_array[10]
                            label.name=csv_array[0]
                            label.firm1=csv_array[3]
                            label.firm2=csv_array[4]
                            label.postal=csv_array[7]
                            label.city=csv_array[8]
                            label.country=csv_array[9]
                            label.street=csv_array[5]
                            label.pob=csv_array[6]
                            label.save
                    end
                    counter += 1
            end
    end

end
```

Controller-Log

```
# Logfile created on 2012-06-06 09:49:23 +0200 by logger.rb/31641
Controller-create-method called! => variables: Params: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"L+fpIMqFA9qe9U/LxU+atFONT8e3L5xEUum1321mRng=", "label"=>{"file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000003df2318 @original_filename="ADRBW076-Q.csv", @content_type="text/csv", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"label[file]\"; filename=\"ADRBW076-Q.csv\"\r\nContent-Type: text/csv\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20120606-2741-1izzofa>>}, "commit"=>"Create Label", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"labels"}<-----> Label: #<Label id: nil, labnr: nil, name: nil, firm1: nil, firm2: nil, postal: nil, city: nil, country: nil, street: nil, pob: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

So! As you can see i want to upload a CSV-file to parse it into my database. A copy of the File should be stored in a folder called CSV for later use. I've done that about 5 times before and it worked well, but this time it seems, that the file-method in the model isn't called.
For now i only want it to work nothing more there will be some changes to catch errors and stuff like that in the future ;).
I've logged the Controller action, which is called every time. May the Logfile can Help you! For me it looks okay, comparing it to other logfiles.
I've searched for a solution, but everything looks okay to me (maybe i've just forgotten a : or a ,), so i can't really say what's wrong!

Thanks for your help

Comment: Don't know what's wrong with your code, but for file uploads I would suggest a library like [CarrierWave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) or [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the Solution!

I am using Rails 3.1.1 with Ruby 1.9.3 and it's gemset. The Problem was the new feature "attr_accessible". Normally not used in Rails 3.1.1 it became necessary to make the :file-Field accessible due to the newer gemset. So the Solution is simple, I just had to add:

```
attr_accessible :file, ect
```

To the Top of my model and everything worked fine!